# Generic repository with generic Id - how to retrieve when int

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, generics

I have a generic repository that is the base class for all repositories in my project. The repository has generic support for the primary key, so it's not necessarily an `int`.

My initial implementation was this, to retrieve an object by ID:

```
return Context.Set<TDomainObject>().Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Where `Id` is type `TPrimaryKey`. When I attempt to use this logic for an `int`, I get a `NotSupportedException` with the message

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context`.

So I thought I'd be clever, and special case where `TPrimaryKey` is `int` and do the evaluation like so:

```
if (typeof(TPrimaryKey) == typeof(int))
{
    int iId = (int)(object)id;
    return Context.Set<TDomainObject>().Where(x => ((int)(object)x.Id) == iId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

This yields a different exception:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.`

How can I make my generic repository work with ints?

Comment: use `return Context.Set<TDomainObject>().Find(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) method

```
return Context.Set<TDomainObject>().Find(id);
```